# NTP offset error from real time

Tags: synchronization, offset, ntp

I'm working on a project where I need to find out the maximum offset an NTP synchronized clock can be from UTC.

If I run ntpdc -c loopinfo it outputs an offset, is this the offset error from actual time?

also if I run ntpq -p it will show offset for each of the peers what is this offset?

which of these can I use to find the maximum offset error from real time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the output of  `ntpq -c kerninfo` or `ntptime`

```
$ ntpq -c kerninfo
associd=0 status=0615 leap_none, sync_ntp, 1 event, clock_sync,
pll offset:            0.336481
pll frequency:         -32.762
maximum error:         0.136773
estimated error:       0.000231
kernel status:         pll nano
pll time constant:     10
precision:             1e-06
frequency tolerance:   500
pps frequency:         0
pps stability:         0
pps jitter:            0.000
calibration interval   4
calibration cycles:    0
jitter exceeded:       0
stability exceeded:    0
calibration errors:    0
```

Or use ntptime:

```
S ntptime
ntp_gettime() returns code 0 (OK)
time d6a66a56.372c300c  Wed, Feb 12 2014 16:47:02.215, (.215518749),
maximum error 141773 us, estimated error 231 us, TAI offset 35
ntp_adjtime() returns code 0 (OK)
modes 0x0 (),
offset 335.660 us, frequency -32.762 ppm, interval 4 s,
maximum error 141773 us, estimated error 231 us,
status 0x2001 (PLL,NANO),
time constant 10, precision 0.001 us, tolerance 500 ppm,
pps frequency 0.000 ppm, stability 0.000 ppm, jitter 0.000 us,
intervals 0, jitter exceeded 0, stability exceeded 0, errors 0.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response dfc. I still have my doubts on ppl offset. Is it the time difference between server and client? Or is it the time difference between client and stratum server? What is maximum error then?

Comment: I am having trouble with your terminology. What is "ppl offset"? And what is the difference between "server and client" and "client and stratum server"?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry about the confusion, I meant pll offset. When I say client I mean my machine which is running an ntpd trying to sync with stratum 2 server. I want to know if the offset that ntpdc -c kerninfo gives is the time difference between my machine and stratum 2 server or is it my machine and stratum 1 server.

Answer (score 0):

> **ntpq -p** will display the offsets for each reachable server in milliseconds (ntpdc -p uses seconds instead).
>
> **ntpdc -c loopinfo** will display the combined offset in seconds, as seen at the last poll. If supported, ntpdc -c kerninfo will display the current remaining correction, just as ntptime does.

https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~ntp/ntpfaq/NTP-s-trouble.htm#Q-TRB-MON-TIME-DIF  :

Answer (score 0):

The above answers are correct for obtaining the stated variables from the NTP service, i.e. error, maxerror. However their definition has always been very unclear to me despite Google searches for NTP web sites and reading NTP man pages. So, I dug into the code and found these two lines https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/stable/ntpd/ntp_loopfilter.c#L780

```
ntv.esterror = (u_int32)(clock_jitter * 1e6);
ntv.maxerror = (u_int32)((sys_rootdelay / 2 + sys_rootdisp) * 1e6);
```

Some additional searching in source found https://github.com/ntp-project/ntp/blob/stable/include/ntpd.h#L473 :

```
extern double    sys_rootdelay;          /* roundtrip delay to primary source */
extern double    sys_rootdisp;           /* dispersion to primary source */
```

Some of this might also be defined somewhere in the NTP specification but I find reading an RFC rather challenging compared to looking through source code.